# variables length differ found

Tags: r, glm

I face problem in r, while doing glm. The problem is, Variable length differ found for "var1". but when I delete this var1 from the data. Then next same type error appear for next variables present in the data. I checked all the data, but there are no length differs in actual. How I resolve this problem? Anyone can please help me. Thanks in advance.
The data is look like; d_status is my response variable and is factor. here doesn't appear because of there are more variables.

```
data.frame':    300 obs. of  20 variables:
```

$ age      : num  28 43 32 64 37 42 36 48 55 31 ...
 $ gender   : num  1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ u_clarity: num  1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ ph       : num  5 5.5 5 5 5 5 5 5.2 5 5 ...
 $ sp_g     : num  1.01 1.02 1.01 1.01 1.01 ...
 $ albumin  : num  1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ glucose  : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ sugar    : num  2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ kb       : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ bpigment : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ ur_bi    : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ blood    : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ pus_cells: num  1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ red_cells: num  1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ epi_cells: num  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ mt       : num  1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ co       : num  2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ gc       : num  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ bacteria : num  1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ cc       : num  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...

> f1=glm(y~.,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=dataset1[training,])
>   Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ ., data = dataset1[training,  : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'age')

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the help page on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include the code that you tried and some sample data so that others can answer your question.

Comment: As Brendan A said, we can't help you unless we're able to reproduce your problem on our systems. That means [edit]ing your question to include a [mcve] of your data and code in the text of the question. You can use the `dput` function to output data in a reproducible format